# YOGA 910 The screen flickers in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: display, display-resolution

I have got a laptop Lenovo Yoga 910. After i try hard to install Ubuntu with Win10, i find that the screen flickers in Ubuntu16.04. I also have tried Ubuntu14.04, the screen is normal.

The VGA controller is

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
```

The graphics card is Intel graphics 620.
I have tried COMMAND `xrandr` to change the resolution. it doesn't work.
If I change the resolution to `1600*900`, it's OK. If I change the resolution to `1920*1080`, the screen will flicker.

Does anyone meet the same problem? And are there any effective solutions?

Comment: Solved. http://askubuntu.com/questions/860810/mangled-and-flickering-graphics-on-yoga-910-with-1920x1080-resolution

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mangled and flickering graphics on Yoga 910 with 1920x1080 resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860810/mangled-and-flickering-graphics-on-yoga-910-with-1920x1080-resolution), you need to add `i915.enable_rc6=0` to `/etc/default/grub`'s line 11, or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Comment: That solution "works" to stop the screen flickering, but it causes the fan to be always on, with periods of excessively high fan noise.   I'm going to post a question about the fan issue -- as I don't see one specific to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

same issue here, solved by rolling back the kernel. now I'm on 4.10.0-041000-generic and the issue is gone. Hope this helps!