# How to install Debian "stretch" kernel (4.9.0-3-amd64) on Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, intel-graphics

I am unable to run Ubuntu 17.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 910 because the kernel (4.10.0-33-generic) has, or is missing, some components related to the kabylake intel-graphics card.  The result is [constant screen tearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945895/solution-to-intel-graphics-screen-tearing-flickering-causes-excessive-fan-use).

I lucked into finding out that the default Debian stretch (and Kali) kernel **4.9.0-3-amd64** resolves this issue.  I would like to install that kernel on an Ubuntu 17.04 install that I have running on another machine.  How do I do so?

For Ubuntu mainline kernels, I would just go [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and download the three .deb files for the kernel version I want (i.e., linux-headers-[version]-all.deb; linux-headers-[version]-amd64.deb; and linux-image-[version]-amd64.deb). Then I would install the .deb files using either `gdebi` or `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Is there an analogous install route for the [Debian stretch kernel](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/kernel/)??  I have tried but there seem to be a lot of depends, and I can't get right combination of files and install sequence.  Here is an image of the files I downloaded from Debian, but could not get right.

[image]

Comment: just a thought:  a recent ubuntu (uk) podcast did a review of a laptop that had come with ubuntu(-mate maybe) where the kernel had been replaced with a non-ubuntu kernel.  it may have been done for your reason (I don't remember the specs) so that maybe an alternative (grab their version; use the kernels) ... but it lead to explanation of what ubuntu do to kernel, why & subsequently what won't work where a non-ubuntu (patched) kernel is used.  (maybe 3-4 weeks ago)

Comment: Download the Debian kernel image .deb and install it.

Comment: You could also rebuild an Ubuntu kernel and add the missing driver to it.

Comment: @smoe -- agreed, IF I knew what it was.  Unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that is exactly what I'm asking how to do.

Comment: You install them with dpkg or package installer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line

Comment: @MBWD, I tend to think that if you do not know about what part of the kernel is responsible and you have not yet run the Debian kernel on the Ubuntu background (since this is what you are asking for) there is a chance that it is not the kernel in the first place but an X driver or firmware package that you are missing with Ubuntu.

Comment: @smoe - good point.  All I know for certain is that the default Debian and Kali installs with the aforementioned kernel work without screen tearing.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the kernel here:  https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
and links for the headers, compiler, and kbuild here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64

Install linux-base, then linux-image
then common headers, compiler and kbuild
then headers-amd
header-all shouldn't be needed.

If you are not building any kernel modules, then the headers, compiler and kbuild are not needed.

NOTE: Although Ubuntu, Debian, and Kali are all debian linux, it is not recommended to mix packages because of minor tweeks done by individual distros.

Comment: Thanks @ravery.  I tried to explain in the original post that I tried that and couldn't figure out the correct order to install those kernel files or right depends needed.  I'll add to the original post an image of the .debs that I downloaded and did not work due to failed order/depends.  If you can help with the exact files and order, that would be awesome.

Comment: @MBWD -- I added an install order. if this leads into a long chain of depends because of different package names between Ubuntu and Debian you might try a mainline kernel and header from kernel.org. the main line packages come without all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I am marking this solved.  I believe that the issue with the kernel install was due to a configuration error on my part when creating the instance I was using.  I re-attempted with a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 and was able to install a 4.9.0 kernel.  This also is a stopgap means to "fix" the screen tearing issues on a Yoga 910.  Apologies for the error.