# Intel NUC5CPYH Ubuntu mouse trail

Tags: intel-graphics

As can be seen in the screenshot, I have a problem with a mouse trail showing up on screen:

[image: screenshot]

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, with Intel graphics driver, and pass trough Yamaha receiver.

Comment: Have you tried to enable vsync?

Comment: Sync to Vblank is enabled in CompizConfig.

Comment: I guess Option "TearFree" "true" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found in the case:
**“Solution” to Intel Graphics Screen Tearing/Flickering Causes Excessive Fan Use in Ubuntu 16.10/17.04/17.10**

The correct solution would be to create the following folder and file:

**sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d**

**gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-graphics.conf**

> you can use any text editor you prefer

copy then paste the following content:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TripleBuffer" "true"
   Option      "TearFree"     "true"
   Option      "DRI"          "true"
EndSection
```

remember to save the file

> Do not create these files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d. That is the
>   location for example configuration files for X, not the ones that are
>   actually loaded.

source:
[Question 945895](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945895/solution-to-intel-graphics-screen-tearing-flickering-causes-excessive-fan-use)