# Parts of desktop glitching on Gnome 3.28.4, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics

Recently upgraded from 14.04 to 18.04 (via 16.04) on Lenovo G580 laptop core i5 3rd gen integrated graphics.

The problem is that only the Gnome part (as i understand it) is glitching. I can scroll within applications like Firefox and watch videos just fine. However, dropdown menus, url and search bar, and rightclick menus show glitching. Pressing super button to get the overview only shows the updated parts of the screen and retains the window image on screen. The clock at the top cycles through the previous two or three minutes. Dragging windows leave trails that flicker and don't go away until I maximize the window and within the window everything is fine.

Is this a Gnome problem or xorg problem? 
I tried this: https://askubuntu.com/a/991391/467766  with no results.

I tried to reduce refresh rate in Compiz, then uninstalled compiz. Did nothing.

EDIT: I logged in from Gnome, Gnome classic, Gnome XORG, Ubuntu Wayland. All have this problem.

EDIT2: After extended use, it turns out that there is slight glitching happening even in applications and videos.

EDIT3: Adding boot parameter `i915.enable_rc6=0` does help, but there is still some glitching and persistence of menus and parts of windows.
`nomodeset` does solve it for the most part except in the windows showcase (pressing super to show workspace). Of course, it runs at 1 fps and is unusable.

EDIT4: I tried the live USB of 20.04, there were no graphics problems.

EDIT5: I did `sudo apt install unity-session xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and logged into Unity and no graphics problems whatsoever. How do I apply this to the Gnome desktop?

EDIT5: I did a fresh install of 20.04 and everything is fine now :/